# JavaScript not working properly on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this simple function to shake a form when the user email is not valid:

```js
function shakeForm() {
  var l = 10;  
  for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ )   
    $("form").animate( { 'margin-left': "+=" + ( l = -l ) + 'px' }, 50);
}
```

You can see on this page that is works fine (just don't insert nothing and push the "Sign up for private beta" button"): http://www.saasmetrics.co/

The problem is: the very same function is not working properly on this second page (please check the end of the page): http://saasmetrics.co/monthly-recurring-revenue/

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please verify that shakeForm is being called and you have set up eventhandlers etc. to deal with your form..

Comment: People won't really be willing to go off and just debug your website for you, and besides, once it's fixed on your website, what value does this question have? Try and narrow the problem down and post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/). As it currently stands, this question isn't suitable for SO.

Comment: I just though it might be a problem related to dependence between .js files, and would be useful to other people facing the problem. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second form has the following class `no-spacing` which will override the `margin-left` in your `shakeForm` function due to the `!important`

```
.no-spacing {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have two shakeform function one in function-page.js and the other in this page http://saasmetrics.co/monthly-recurring-revenue/ so you have first two declaration of the same function maybe this can be the problem.